# Trying to add two <ol> in doc export but they are merged into one <ol>

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the html included in the doc export function

```
<table width="500px">
    <tr>
        <td><h4><span class="language_l1">{{ $leftdata->title }}</span></h4></td>
        <td><h4><span class="language_l1">{{ $rightdata->title }}</span></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ol type="a">
                <?php $i=1;?>
                    @foreach($leftdata->options as $key => $value)
                    <li>
                        <span class="language_l1">{!! $value !!} </span>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
            </ol>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ol type="a">
                <?php $i=1;?>
                    @foreach($rightdata->options as $key => $value)
                    <li>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                        <span class="language_l1">{!! $value !!} </span>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
            </ol>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is a screenshot of what I get in the doc file

[image]

You can see that the 2  is merged into the same list as you can see the second list starts from d but it supposed to start from a.
So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `start` attribute like this `start="1"` to your `OL` elements. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) this will declare the starting letter of your list.